# Spring Boot Oauth2 Client(Reactive) Mutual TLS/SSL token uri

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

**Spring boot** 2.3.x and Spring 5.x had recently added the support for configuring the reactive oauth2 client based on the [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) class.

I had a requirement for the Client Credentials grant flow configuration

Doing this call without the Mutual TLS/SSL is quiet straight forward.

Normal (without TLS/SSL) configuration (`@Configuration`) the code extract is as below:-

```
@Bean
public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
        ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository){

    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
            .clientCredentials()
            .build();

    DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);

    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
    return authorizedClientManager;
}

@Bean("testClient")
public WebClient webClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager,
                           @Value("${test.client.base.url}") String baseUrl) {
    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauthFunction = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    oauthFunction.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("local");
    return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .filter(oauthFunction)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.oauth2Client();
    return http.build();
}
```

The properties file

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.local.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.local.client-id=client_id
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.local.client-secret=client_secret

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.local.token-uri=http://hostname:port/oauth/token
test.client.base.url=http://protected-resource/v1/apis
```

But calling the oauth2 authorization server over Mutual TLS(Client cert) was a big deal.

How to do that? I would like to share the same with the community and would answer the same myself below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the requirement and the main change will be in the bean `authorizedClientManager`

The scope of the answer is the client credentials grant flow only though changes for the other oauth2 grant flows should be similar and this would help there too.

```
@Bean
public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
        ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository){

    // construct client credential token response client yourself
    WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient = new WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();

    // construct the sslContext as per your needs and inject in below
    // and create httpClient by injecting your sslContext here
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
            .tcpConfiguration(client -> client.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000))
            .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext));

    ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);

    accessTokenResponseClient.setWebClient(WebClient.builder().clientConnector(httpConnector).build());

    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder
            .builder()
            .clientCredentials(c -> {
                c.accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient);
            }).build();

    DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);

    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
    return authorizedClientManager;
}
```

Here if you see the line `.secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext));`

You need to construct the sslContext and inject the same, and that would depend entirely on your code setup.

For detailed code and instructions you can go to the link [here](https://medium.com/@karanbir.tech/spring-boot-oauth2-mutual-tls-client-client-credentials-grant-3cdb7a2a44ea?source=friends_link&sk=27a661a17bb8a26d36622222d061fc50)